# R: randomly sampling a dataframe based on another dataframe with a range

Tags: r, dataframe, range, inner-join, sample

So I have 2 dataframes, one (dfA) with climate data that has over 100,000 rows, and one (dfB) as a list of sampling criteria (seed zone, altitude, and freq) with only about 50 rows.

What I'm aiming to do is use dfB as a basis to randomly sample rows from dfA based on shared columns (seed zone and altitude), picking n rows based on the freq column. This has been successful! The first code below is what I have managed to make work as far as I can tell, but it gives very limited results as the values have to match exactly and very few do.

Ideally, what I'd like to do, is have the sampling happen as above, but across a range of altitudes based on the dfB$Altitude value (say +-10)

Code for basic sampling (works):

```
sample <- dfA %>%
  inner_join(dfB) %>% 
  group_by(Seed_zone, Altitude) %>%
  sample_n(first(freq))
```

Code I've tried (in multiple variations) that hasn't worked

```
sample <- dfA %>%
  filter(dfA > dfB -10 & dfA < dfB +10) %>%
  left_join(dfB, by = c("Seed_zone")) %>%
  group_by(Seed_zone) %>%
  sample_n(first(freq))
```

dfA example data

| Climate data | Altitude | Seed_zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.107707 | 305 | 101 |
| 4.845323 | 499 | 203 |
| 2.985152 | 7 | 101 |
| 22.17268 | 299 | 101 |

dfB example data

| Altitude | Seed_zone | freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 101 | 2 |
| 502 | 203 | 1 |

Expected outcome (using +- 10)

| Climate data | Altitude | Seed_zone | freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.107707 | 305 | 101 | 2 |
| 4.845323 | 499 | 203 | 1 |
| 22.17268 | 299 | 101 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `join_by`. Note that when joining on an inequality, we cannot calculate on the fly, so we pre-calc the +/-0 10.

```r
library(dplyr)
dfB %>%
  mutate(m10 = Altitude-10, p10 = Altitude+10) %>%
  inner_join(dfA, join_by(Seed_zone, m10 <= Altitude, p10 >= Altitude), suffix = c(".B", "")) %>%
  group_by(Seed_zone, Altitude.B) %>%
  sample_n(first(freq)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#   Altitude.B Seed_zone  freq   m10   p10 `Climate data` Altitude
#        <int>     <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>    <int>
# 1        300       101     2   290   310           5.11      305
# 2        300       101     2   290   310          22.2       299
# 3        502       203     1   492   512           4.85      499
```

In this case, `Altitude.B` is from `dfB` (ergo why I intentionally change the suffix) and `Altitude` is the original from `dfA` (I thought it easier to keep this unchanged .. perhaps I should have used `suffix = c(".B", ".A")`).

Comment: The issue I'm getting now is:
Error in 'sample_n()':
Can't compute indices
In group 1: 'Seed_zone = 101', 'Altitude.B = 300'.
Caused by error:
'size' must be less than or equal to 1 (size of data)

Comment: Also if I change sample_n() to slice_sample(n = freq) I get:
Error in 'slice_sample()':
'n' must be a round number, not a <standardGeneric> object.

Comment: Good news! It's a slightly messy output but I can get it to work by changing it to:

sample_n(size = first(freq), replace = TRUE)